# SWIG [C++ to Lisp(CFFI)] error when compiling wrapper

Tags: c++, common-lisp, wrapper, swig, cffi

I'm a beginner with interface between C++ and Lisp with SWIG. I've follow the SWIG's documentation but I'm facing a problem.
Here is the simple program I want to interface (It can easily be done in Lisp but it is to understand how to import C++ code into Lisp):

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.hpp"
int test(int x, int y) {
   std::cout << x+y;
   return 0;
}
```

test.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>
int test(int x, int y);
```

In order to use SWIG, I create the interface file:

test.i:

```
%module test
%include <test.hpp>
```

And, I've execute the following command line:

```
$ swig -c++ -cffi test.i 
$ c++ -c test_wrap.cxx
```

But when compiling the test_wrap.cxx, the terminal says:

```
test_wrap.cxx:193:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'test'
result = (int)test(arg1,arg2);
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modified `test.i` which makes the rest compile:

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.hpp"
%}

%include <test.hpp>
```

I followed [this presentation](http://www.swig.org/papers/PyTutorial98/PyTutorial98.pdf) (page 24) and apparently you need to insert the `include` directive in the generated wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I needed ;)